# Android Studio Android Device Monitor can't access File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I recently changed my laptop and the Android Studio seemed to have some problem with it.

I used to view the data of the AVD from the Android Device Monitor -> File Explorer, and I do know that you can't access the data folder of a real device. It's not about that. I'm talking about the AVD I created, and I used to be able to view the files through File Explorer all the time.

As you could see in the below screenshot, the File Explorer is EMPTY, it wasn't like this when using my old laptop. I figured it might be due to some access denial, so I turned to my Android Studio installation folder and grant full access to all users. It still doesn't work.

Here's a screen shot of my current Android Device Monitor:
[I noticed a lot of denial and reject log in the LogCat window, I'm not sure if it's always the case, simply didn't pay attention before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMPLS.png)

Comment: The File Explorer hasn't worked for me in several months, so it's not just you. I have assumed that an Android Studio or tools update broke it.

Comment: LOL, I guess I should keep the Android Studio in my old laptop un-updated for now. Thank you so much!

Comment: This one is reproducable on new emulators for me in the same time for 4.4.4 simulator I can see files

Comment: It works fine for me now, Android Studio is constantly updating and patching, so just keep it up-to-date and if the problem still exists, wait for the next update, lol.